# Cumulative summing values in a dataframe based on a value in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the two dataframes: the first shows a customer's orders with the product they ordered, the order date, and the quantity they ordered, the second shows a master list of all orders placed by all customers.

```
customer_id   product_id  order_date  quantity
1             001         1/5/2022    10
1             002         1/5/2022    10
```

```
customer_id   product_id  order_date  quantity
1             001         1/5/2022    10
1             002         1/5/2022    10
2             001         1/1/2022    5
3             001         1/2/2022    10
3             002         1/6/2022    10
4             002         1/6/2022    5
5             002         1/10/2022   10
5             001         1/10/2022   5
```

What I need to do is count the quantity of orders placed before customer_id 1 placed theirs to determine the quantity needed to fulfill all the orders for customer_id 1 can receive their order. For example, for customer_id 1 to receive their order of product_id 001, a quantity of 25 is needed (customer_id 2 and 3 ordered 5 and 10 respectively, and customer_id 1 ordered 10).

So all customers who placed orders for product_id 001 should be counted (i.e.: customer_id 5 placed their order after customer_id 1, so their quantity of 5 doesn't need to be counted).

```
customer_id   product_id  order_date  quantity  quantity_needed
1             001         1/5/2022    10        25
1             002         1/5/2022    10        35
```

I tried to use some form of the .cumsum() function, but I'm not sure how to cumulative sum by groups of values.

Comment: Shouldn't `quantity_needed` equal `30` for `product_id=1`? You have `10+5+10+5`? Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: customer_id 5 ordered after customer_id 1 (on 1/10/2022), so it would be 25

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        data={
            "customer_id": [1, 1],
            "product_id": ["001", "002"],
            "order_date": ["1/5/2022", "1/5/2022"],
            "quantity": [10, 10]
        })
    
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(
        data={
            "customer_id": [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5],
            "product_id": ["001", "002", "001", "001", "002", "002", "002", "001"],
            "order_date": ["1/5/2022", "1/5/2022", "1/1/2022", "1/2/2022", "1/6/2022", "1/6/2022", "1/10/2022",
                           "1/10/2022"],
            "quantity": [10, 10, 5, 10, 10, 5, 10, 5]
        })
    
    df1["order_date"] = df1["order_date"].map(pd.Timestamp)
    df2["order_date"] = df2["order_date"].map(pd.Timestamp)
    
    def func(row):
        cust = row["customer_id"]
        prod = row["product_id"]
        d = row["order_date"]
        mask =  (df2["product_id"] == prod) & (df2["order_date"] <= d)
        return df2.loc[mask]["quantity"].sum()
    
    df1["quantity_needed"] = df1.apply(func, axis=1)
    print(df1.to_string())
    result = '''
       customer_id product_id order_date  quantity  quantity_needed
    0            1        001 2022-01-05        10               25
    1            1        002 2022-01-05        10               10
    '''
```

Not sure how the quantity needed is 35 for 002, can you clarify?
For product id 001:

- We filter the second dataframe with product id and date
- We return the sum of the quantity matching our criteria